# Gmail - Adding a comment or tags to archived emails

Tags: gmail, archiving

**Can you add some tags and a description to a Gmail email when you archive it, to make it easier to find later?**

In Gmail, when archiving an important email, it's not always straightforward to see months or years down the line why I archived it or what it's for. Also, sometimes the email itself doesn't contain the right keywords that will actually help me find it when I need it.

I would like to be able to write some keywords or even a short description when I archive some emails which will make it easier for me to find them in the future and understand why it was important for me to keep them.

Is there a way to do that that, or maybe a workaround to achieve a similar effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a label. The label can be anything you want. The best part is that a message can have more than one label.

The presence of a label doesn't interfere with the conversation being in the inbox. When you no longer want to see it in the inbox, click the archive button to strip the inbox label. The conversation will still have the rest of the labels.

The label makes it easy to find via search or by using the list of labels on the edge of the window.  Your search can include multiple labels, or words in the message or title, and who sent it to you.

I have found that the use of labels works well with the Multiple inbox feature. For example I use one of the sections to display all my medical related conversations from the current year. They have a label that includes the year so they are easy to find, display and search.

Answer (score -1):

Forward the message to yourself (or "reply" but change the recipient to yourself) and include the notes in message body. Gmail's conversation threading will group the notes together with the original.